# Is a comma required between two independent clauses in a compound sentence?

Tags: commas, independent-clauses

A colleague in our department has written a comma assessment for our students. One of the sentences in the assessment is

> Instead the topic became one of contention and before dinner was over she had left the restaurant and hailed a cab.

I'm assuming that the correct punctuation would be:

> Instead, the topic became one of contention, and before dinner was over, she had left the restaurant and hailed a cab.

My colleague insists that there shouldn't be a comma after the word *contention*, even though it appears we have two dependent clauses. Who is in the right?

Answer (score 1):

There is no question that there should be a comma after "contention." A comma must be used between two independent clauses joined by a conjunction, except when those independent clauses are very short.

Comment: Some reading material on brianpck's answer: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conjunctions.htm

Comment: The argument from my colleague is that you're not technically joining two independent clauses as the words "before dinner was over" is actually a dependent clause.

Comment: There are two independent clauses: "Instead the topic became one of contention" and "Before dinner was over she had left the restaurant and hailed a cab." You are right that "before dinner was over" is dependent: but it is "dependent" on the second complex sentence. The combined sentence is compound-complex, and both independent sentences that make it up must be separated by a comma if they are joined by a conjunction.

Answer (score -1):

Using only commas, this is a run-on sentence. It needs a semi-colon after *contention*, not a comma.

> Instead, the topic became one of contention; and before dinner was over, she had left the 
>   restaurant and hailed a cab.

Ideally, this would be two separate sentences, omitting the word *and*:

> Instead, the topic became one of contention. Before dinner was over, she had left the 
>   restaurant and hailed a cab.